# php YII Apache2 or Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx, yii, apache2

I'm completly new to YII and I want to self educate on this framework.

But for a start, should I use Apache2 of Nginx with YII? There is a page that gives info about the two, but not which one to choose (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.apache-nginx-config)

What would you guys suggest?

Comment: Apache To get good support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one works just fine.  Apache tends to be better know and more widely supported.  If memory isn't an issue on your dev box, choose Apache, it's faster to get up and going.

If you need your server go as fast as possible, Nginx is a good choice.

Because you're just trying to self educate, probably simpler to go with Apache.